# get items with A value if they dont have B value in a join query ( repetitive items )

Tags: php, mysql, sql, normalization

sorry if the title is vague .

i have these table :

```
image : id , title 
image_tags : image_id , tag 
image_categories  : image_id , category_id
```

in the image page , i want to get similar images by tag , from the same category but i want to exclude some categories

so here is my query :(lets say my curernt image has `category : 1 , tag : a,b` and i want to ignore `category : 6,7`)

```
SELECT image_tags.image_id 
FROM   image_tags 
       JOIN image_categories 
         ON image_categories.image_id = image_tags.image_id 
WHERE  image_tags.tag IN ( 'a', 'b' ) && image_categories.category_id IN ( 1 ) 
       && 
              image_categories.category_id NOT IN ( 6, 7 )
```

that works but if i have

```
       image_tags ( image_id , tag ) : 
        `128` , `a`
    --------------------------------------------
        image_categories (image_id , category_id ) :
        `128` , `1`
        `128` , `6`
```

i'll get the image with `id = 128` on account of the first row in the `image_categories`

i have to somehow check and ignor image `128` becuz if second row ( `category_i : 6` )

hopefully my question is not very confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group on `image_id` and test the categories using a suitable aggregate function within the `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT   image_id
FROM     image_tags JOIN image_categories USING (image_id)
WHERE    image_tags.tag IN ('a','b')
GROUP BY image_id
HAVING   SUM(image_categories.category_id IN (1))
     AND NOT SUM(image_categories.category_id IN (6,7))
```

Comment: i thought `sum` is for adding values ( i've to say i've never seen it to be used like this)

Comment: @max: It is.  However, MySQL doesn't have true booleans - it instead uses `1` for true and `0` for false.  Thus taking the sum of such expressions over a group will yield `0` if the expression is false for the entire group; and non-zero if it is true for any record within the group.

Comment: @max: In other RDBMS, one would have to be more explicit - e.g. `SUM(CASE WHEN image_categories.category_id IN (1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0`.

Comment: @max `SUM` or `MAX` can be used to express "any" whereas `MIN` can be used to say "none".

Comment: thanx , what if i want to only exlude 6,7 category (get all categories except these two) ? i'ts probably not ging to work if i remove `HAVING   SUM(image_categories.category_id IN (1))`